# Rails Parse JSON to hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, parsing

I try parse JSON response.

```
@response = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(@data.body)
```

@response:

```
{"response"=>[{"name"=>"Den", "other"=>[{"sex"=>"male"}]}]}
```

how to access

```
@response['response']['name']
```

and

```
@response['response']['name']['sex']
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
@response['response'][0]['name']
```

and

```
@response['response'][0]['other'][0]['sex']
```